# How do you use Netbeans to work with a Github project?

Tags: netbeans, github

From what I can tell, nbGit doesn't talk to Github.  The best idea I've had so far is to install msysgit, use it to clone the repository to the local drive, then point nbGit at the local clone (creating a second repository).  Then I would use nbGit to talk to the repository on disk, and msysgit to sync the on-disk repository with Github.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for the git pull and push commands does not look like it is yet implemented within the nbGit plugin - see [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/issues/detail?id=41) for details... So I think using the command line to sync with github might be your best option for a little while still.

Comment: See also an answer to this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477259/is-there-a-way-to-work-with-netbeans-and-github-synchronize-them/4557360#4557360 asked a couple of weeks later, which has some information and links regarding native Git support in NetBeans 7.0.