# Is there a way to work with Netbeans and Github, synchronize them

Tags: netbeans, github

Is there a way to work with Netbeans and Github, synchronize them

Github plugin for Netbeans or something

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838465/how-do-you-use-netbeans-to-work-with-a-github-project

Answer (score 11):

**Update**

NetBeans 7.0 now has native support for Git at some level of functionality. It is available from the "Plugin Portal" Update Center (Tools|Plugins, then "Available Plugins").

See the [NetBeans Git Integration Plan](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_plan) for supported features and a development roadmap.

---

There is a git plugin for NetBeans called [NBGit](http://nbgit.org/). Note that it self-describes as experimental. There are links at the [NBGit.org](http://nbgit.org/) site to [its Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/), and it appears that the actual source code has moved over to [its GitHub project](http://github.com/myabc/nbgit) if you're looking for the bleeding edge. Development activity on the project appears to be thin and sporadic lately.

I've used NBGit several months ago, and found it to be a fair start, but not feature-complete enough to use for my day-to-day work. As mentioned in a [previously-asked question](/questions/1838465/how-do-you-use-netbeans-to-work-with-a-github-project), there are several basic commands missing that you need to go to the command-line or a dedicated GUI for.

It appears that [NetBeans version 7.0](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_70) may include some level of [native support for Git](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_main). Note, however, that the 7.0 planning document (first link in this paragraph) says "*GIT support, in early access, AU only (preview)*," which may mean that 7.0 will only contain a basic implementation like NBGit, and that we may have to wait for 7.1++ for feature-complete support.

Note that **there is nothing special about working with Git repositories on [GitHub](http://github.com)**. GitHub simply hosts the repositories. Any proper Git client can access repositories hosted there.

(On the other hand, GitHub does have it's own [GitHub API](http://develop.github.com/) to access the features specific to their web site / web app. That would be something different than working with the repos through an IDE though.)

Comment: so anyway, how to make our netbeans working to push (update / commit) files to the github repo? 
I seek too many articles but they're not using nb.6.9 is that real? :D