# Git hub how to add repository to Netbeans?

Tags: git, netbeans, github, netbeans-plugins

I'm new to GitHub.

I just registered, because my client use it. He added me to repository, so  I can see it now on gitHub website.

I worked with SVN, but not with Git.

I use Netbeans IDE and there is a plugin for git. I just want to know, how can I create local copy of repository and how do I need to do commit.

I'm just afraid to do it myself, because I can corrupt data.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [NBGit plugin](http://nbgit.org/) to your NetBeans: you will then been able to clone your repo.
Don't fear any data corruption - worst case, you could end up corrupting your *local* copy, but there won't be any consequence on the GitHub side.

Note: The clone or pull itself would still be made by hand (in a command-line interface): what was reported in "[How do you use Netbeans to work with a Github project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838465/how-do-you-use-netbeans-to-work-with-a-github-project)" is still accurate.

[NetBeans 7.0](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_70) [has a native Git support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477259/is-there-a-way-to-work-with-netbeans-and-github-synchronize-them/4557360#4557360), but it is still a bit immature.

Comment: Thanks. Just one question. This is what I do Group->Git->Clone other

then I insert repository url (ssh) and there is need to insert username and password. 

This is not my repository, my client added me to it. So do I need to insert my github account username and password? or any other login details?

Comment: @Ahmed: So I suppose you are using NB7.0.1 (http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_plan#M5_%2814._May_2011,_planned_for_7.0.1%29) which has clone support. I would rather use the https address, rather than the ssh one. That means setting my GitHub token once cloned: http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/. And that means having a `.netrc` (or `_netrc` on Windows) file, with github.com, login an password in it.